# setBounds value for width that will set width to minimum?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, setbounds

Is there a value that can be put into setBounds to set the width to the minimum needed?

```
JLabel title = new JLabel("Title Text");
title.setBounds(50, 20, ?, 13);
```

Rather than using guess & check to find the minimum width, is there a value I can use?

Comment: With swing, the layout decides what size a component will have so calling setBounds is ignored. You can however influence the sizes swing will use with calls to `setPreferredSize(Dimension d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the text that will be in the `JLabel` (i.e., if that text won't change after being assigned once), there is no need to set the minimum width; the `JLabel` should do so automatically.

Comment: Okay, but what value would I use?

Comment: You wouldn't use any; you wouldn't use `setBounds()` at all. `JLabel`s resize automatically to fit whatever you put in them.

Comment: What do you recommend I use to place the label in a specific location? For some reason, setLocation does not work.

Comment: I would suggest using a layout manager of some kind... `MiGLayout` is awesome for a grid-based layout (it's very flexible.) If you don't want to use a layout at all, check out this link: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).